Bootstrap.js failed to compile : symfony/stimulus-bundle
Context :
Creating a new webapp in symfony 7 lead me to compile error while attempting to build assets with webpack.
Error

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
00:13:02 Module build failed: Module not found:

"./assets/bootstrap.js" contains a reference to the file "@symfony/stimulus-bundle".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.


Solution :
It's seems that it's due to the AssetMapper which is installed by default when creating a new webapp project.
If you prefer to use webpack to manage your assets, follow the link below to the documentation to switch from AssetMapper to Webpack properly :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#switch-from-assetmapper

Hello, you should answer to yourself and mark it as verified. It worked for me :)

Solution :
It's seems that it's due to the AssetMapper which is installed by default when creating a new webapp project.
If you prefer to use webpack to manage your assets, follow the link below to the documentation to switch from AssetMapper to Webpack properly :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#switch-from-assetmapper
#Remove AssetMapper & Turbo/Stimulus temporarily
composer remove symfony/ux-turbo symfony/asset-mapper symfony/stimulus-bundle

# Add Webpack Encore and Turbo/Stimulus back
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle symfony/ux-turbo symfony/stimulus-bundle

# Install and build assets
npm install
npm run dev


Apart from pointing a link for the solution. You could give the example commands with a little explanation because links can always change as you know.
